# I want to split an image into small, equally-sized tiles

Tags: software-recommendation, photos, software

I’m an artist with a stupid question, the answer to which might easy…

I have need of a process that can segment an image into a specified number of equal-sized tiles, that will then go through a separate image processor (it can't handle large files in one go; splitting them up into discreet tiles allows this), to be stitched-back together later (I was going to use PhotoStitcher or something like it).

Any ideas as to how to achieve this? I have racked my brains without an answer!

Thanks, guys

MisterGee

Comment: That sounds horribly messy & most probably an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) ... what type of image files? How big is the image? What process are you trying to achieve that cannot be done to a whole image?

Comment: Looks like imagemagick could [probably do this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile), but it's a bit of a [faff to install](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#macosx) if you're not already using MacPorts or Homebrew. There are third-party apps offering similar functionality, e.g. [Tile Photos FX](http://www.appsoftstudio.com/Image-Slices.html) (never used it and have no opinion on it). The cropping capability of the built-in `sips` command may also be of use, but would require some bash- or Apple-scripting to generate every tile.